# How to create a infinite list if input is not delcared?

Tags: prolog

I have a written a functional function that tells the user if a list is ordered or not, given the list inputted. However, if a user inputs a variable as the input instead of a list, I would like to output an infinite list. How can I go about this? Here is the current code

```
ordered([]).
ordered([_]).
ordered([X,Y|Ys]) :- X =< Y , ordered( [Y|Ys] ).
```

Here is some input

```
? ordered([1,2,3]).
true
? ordered([1,5,2]).
false
```

I also want for variables to creat infinite list like so

```
? ordered(L).
L = [];
L = [_1322] ;
L = [_1322, _1323] ;
L = [_1322, _1323, _1324] ;
L = [_1322, _1323, _1324, _1325].
```

The list should increase until the user exits as shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The list should increase until the user exits as shown.

Solution:

```
ordered([]).
ordered([_]).
ordered([X,Y|Ys]) :- X #=< Y , ordered( [Y|Ys] ).
```

**EDIT**:

[SWI Prolog doc](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%23%3D%3C/2)

> The arithmetic expression X is less than or equal to Y. When reasoning over integers, replace (=<)/2 by #=</2 to obtain more general relations. See declarative integer arithmetic (section A.9.3).

Comment: The following succeeds: `?- ordered(List), List = [3, 2, 1].` This isn't great from a logical point of view.

Answer (score 3):

What properties should the list of variables have? The currently accepted answer by Anton Danilov says that `[3, 2, 1]` is not an ordered list:

```
?- List = [A, B, C], List = [3, 2, 1], ordered(List).
false.
```

but it also says that `[3, 2, 1]` is an instance of an ordered list:

```
?- List = [A, B, C], ordered(List), List = [3, 2, 1].
List = [3, 2, 1],
A = 3,
B = 2,
C = 1 ;
false.
```

Viewed *logically*, this is a contradiction. Viewed *procedurally*, it is fine, but also the `@=<` relationship between the variables in the list is meaningless. The comparison of the unbound variables does not say anything about the relationship of the list elements if they are bound to values at some point.

You can use constraints to exclude future unordered bindings:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

ordered([]).
ordered([_]).
ordered([X, Y | Xs]) :-
    X #=< Y,
    ordered([Y | Xs]).
```

This way you cannot bind the variables in the list to incorrect numbers later on:

```
?- List = [A, B, C], List = [3, 2, 1], ordered(List).
false.

?- List = [A, B, C], ordered(List), List = [3, 2, 1].
false.
```

But later correct ordered bindings are still allowed:

```
?- List = [A, B, C], ordered(List), List = [1, 2, 3].
List = [1, 2, 3],
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 3 ;
false.
```

Comment: The following query causes a stack overflow error, when the uses tries to find a second solution: ```?- ordered(List), List = [1, 2, 3].```.

Comment: Yes. That is because `ordered(List)` tries to generate more and more solutions: lists of length 4, 5, 6, and so on, until infinity. None of those lists unifies with `[1, 2, 3]`, but Prolog keeps trying until the memory fills up. There is no way around this with a predicate that generates an unbounded number of solutions. Unless it is lazy like yours, which I like!

Comment: See my solution, it works even for the query ```?- ordered(List), List = [1, 2, 3].```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the best solution, but I believe it can give you some idea of how to do what you need. In SWI-Prolog, the predicate `freeze(+Var,:Goal)` delays the execution of `Goal` until `Var` is bound.

```
ordered([]).
ordered([_]).
ordered([X,Y|R]) :- 
   freeze( X, 
           freeze( Y, 
                   ( X @=< Y, 
                     ordered([Y|R]) ) ) ).
```

Here are some examples with finite lists:

```
?- ordered([1,2,3]).
true.

?- ordered([1,2,3,0]).
false.

?- ordered(L), L=[1,2,3].
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.

?- ordered(L), L=[1,2,3,0].
false.
```

For an infinite list, you will need to "take" its prefix:

```
take([]).
take([_|R]) :- take(R).
```

Here is an example with infinite list:

```
?- ordered(L), take(L).
L = [] ;
L = [_375396] ;
L = [_376366, _376372],
freeze(_376366, freeze(_376372,  (_376366@=<_376372, ordered([])))) ;
L = [_377472, _377478, _377484],
freeze(_377472, freeze(_377478,  (_377472@=<_377478, ordered([_377484])))) ;
L = [_378590, _378596, _378602, _378608],
freeze(_378590, freeze(_378596,  (_378590@=<_378596, ordered([_378602, _378608])))) ;
L = [_379720, _379726, _379732, _379738, _379744],
freeze(_379720, freeze(_379726,  (_379720@=<_379726, ordered([_379732, _379738, _379744]))))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the recursive call be `ordered([Y | R])`? Otherwise I think you would accept `[1, 2, 0]`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I've already corrected that error.